# MSBuild Error on too many warnings

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to clear our project of warnings, and I would like to create some sort of check in the msbuild, so insure that the number of warnings won't go up.

Is there any way to fail the build in case the number of warnings is higher then a particular number?

Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Are you running your build through a solution, a single project, or a msbuild script building other items?

Comment: I'm running a msbuild on remote build machine.
I'm willing to add to this msbuild some sort of script or even a console executable.

Comment: You still did not answer the question.  What exactly are you are building?  Is a project, a solution, or a msbuild script?

Comment: There is a way using build process templates. However, if you're looking to solely accomplish this in MSBuild, then I'm not sure how to do it.